# how do i rewrite URL such as

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite my web URL such as

```
http://www.site.com/profile/ -> profile.php
http://www.site.com/settings/ -> settings.php
```

and another word of profile and settinhs is link to user.php

example,

if I push http://www.site.com/**giffary**/ - it's link to user.php?name=**giffary**

but when i push http://www.site.com/profile/ - it's link to profile.php not user.php.

how can i write .htaccess file

thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `mod_rewrite` for this, obviously.  I have not tested it, but this config *should* work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Ignore URLs that point to files/directories that actually exist.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Special rewrites
RewriteRule ^/profile/?$ /profile.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/settings/?$ /settings.php [L]

# User profile rewrites
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/?$ /user.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Comment: As a side note, this config will map both /profile and /profile/ to profile.php.  In fact, the trailing slash is optional in all cases.  If you want it to be required, remove the ? following the / in the RewriteRule directives.

Comment: what is [L] in each last of statement?

Comment: That means "last" -- once any of the rules match, it will stop processing any further rules.